# Windows.System.User.GetPictureAsync returning generic gray user image

Tags: c#, uwp

In my UWP project, I want to display the currently logged in user's picture in an `<Image>`.

In my view:

```
<Image x:Name="picUser"></Image>
```

In the view's code behind:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    var user = (await Windows.System.User.FindAllAsync(Windows.System.UserType.LocalUser, Windows.System.UserAuthenticationStatus.LocallyAuthenticated)).FirstOrDefault();
    var streamReference = await user.GetPictureAsync(Windows.System.UserPictureSize.Size64x64);
    if (streamReference != null)
    {
        Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream stream = await streamReference.OpenReadAsync();
        var bitmapImage = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
        picUser.Source = bitmapImage;
    }
}
```

While debugging, the streamReference is indeed not null, but the Image is displaying a generic, gray user icon, however I made sure that my user's image is set.

My goal would be to display that image, instead of the placeholder.

Comment: Might `FindAllAsync` be capable of returning multiple results? The name certainly suggests so, so how do you know that `FirstOrDefault` is returning the correct one? I'd suggest digging deeper there (obtaining all users and investigating the various properties to see what account(s) are being returned)

Comment: Indeed, it is capable of returning more than one result, but I'm certain that the content of the user variable is my local user's.

Comment: I am having this issue even today. When I've narrowed down my user in the collection, the image still comes back as the default image.